# Multi-threaded SQLITE access. Leaving a connection open vs opening/closing for every transaction

Tags: database, sqlite, connection

I'm working on a rather large scale application that has multiple threads accessing sqlite3 via c++.  I'm currently giving them each a database connection and using mutexes to make sure nothing is ever reading at the same time as a write.

This appears to be working fine, but after a while of running (seems to be around 13 hours), something happens with the database and I'm no longer able to access it from either connection (says database is locked for a while, and then switches to unable to open database file).

I have not been able to track down the cause of this issue (as it only happens after about 13 hours of running), but I'm wondering if I should perhaps it's due to leaving connections open for long periods of time.

Would it be better to have my threads open and close new connections every time they want to access the database? Or is it okay for them to keep open connections for extended periods of time?

Comment: Don't try to randomly guess where your program is failing; you won't get very far. Try to reliably reproduce the problem instead.

Comment: Also, why have multiple connections if you're using a mutex to prevent concurrent access? Either go through one shared connection using your mutex to control access, or give each thread its own connection and let sqlite handle locking the file (which it's perfectly capable of doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases is better to keep connections. This is because creating new connection takes time. Please review your code and check some death connections.